# Sublime GDB for Sublime 3 doesn't work: You have not configured the plugin correctly

Tags: sublimetext3

I've googled this issue and haven't seen any useful advice. My understanding is that the default settings should work; I can't see any information about mandatory modifications to the default settings.

```
You have not configured the plugin correctly, the default configuration file and your user configuration file will open in a new window
```

when I try to open the debugger, then it opens the user settings (an empty file) and the sublimeGDB settings file, which seems like it's the default. The setup tutorial on https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeGDB doesn't mention needing to modify any files, only that doing so is possible if you want to change your preferences.

Also, I do not understand the following instruction:

```
Open up the default settings via the command palette and begin typing GDB and select the default.
```

When I open the command palette, there is no "default" option when I type in GDB, only a list of SublimeGDB features (all of which lead to the titular error)

I installed SublimeGDB with package control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at your `SublimeGDB.sublime-settings` and you read some properties you can see that their values are set to `"notset"`

As the very minimum you have to set those:

```
"workingdir": "${folder:${file}}",
"commandline": "gdb --interpreter=mi --args ./${file_base_name}",
"env": {"DISPLAY": ":100"},
```

The working dir is the directory of the current open file.

This will launch the executable file that is named like the file you have currently open (without extension)

There are many others settings and options.

You need to read and learn how to configure them in order that they fit your needs.

Comment: Can you elaborate little more what `{"DISPLAY": ":100"}` means?

Comment: I would like to be able to launch executable with few different arguments e.g. without modifying the settings file. Would this be somehow possible? I tried to use "variants" within the settings but no use.
```lang-json
    // Arguments for the program.
    // Example: to run "./executable foo bar"
    // "arguments": "foo bar"
    // To provide user input (stdin) use
    // "arguments": "< input.dat"
    "arguments": "",
```